# Strict stubbing argument mismatch when use @Value

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

`any()` matcher for @Value field gives `Strict stubbing argument mismatch` error.

Is there any `ArgumentMatcher` proper to @Value field? And maybe someone knows why 'any()' is not working?

Field (`sampleVersion`), which I get from application.properties using @Value annotation, has in test  value `null` (proof - first line of logs). Even logs show that there is `null` and matcher expected `null`.

PS I solved this problem using this:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someClass, "serviceUrl", "value");
```

but I'm curious is it necessary and why simple `any()` doesn't work.

Logs:

```
sampleVersion has value: null

Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'postForEntity' method:
    restTemplate.postForEntity(
    null,
    <{key=null},[Content-Type:"application/json"]>,
    class java.lang.String
);
    -> at com.some.package.SomeClass.someMethod(SomeClass.java:126)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.postForEntity(null, null, null);
      -> at com.some.package.SomeClassTest.someTest(SomeClassTest.java:59)
```

Method:

```
    @Value("${sample.version}")
    private String sampleVersion;

    public ResponseEntity someMethod()  {

    System.out.println("sampleVersion has value: " + sampleVersion);

    Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramMap.put("key", sampleVersion);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    return restTemplate.postForEntity(sampleVersion, new HttpEntity<>(paramMap, headers), String.class);
    }
```

Test:

```
    @InjectMocks
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

    @Test
    void someTest() {
    //given
    ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity("{ \"text\" : \"hello\"}", HttpStatus.OK);

    //when
    when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(response);
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = someClass.someMethod();

    assertNotNull(responseEntity);
    }
```

Environment:

Java 11
SpringBoot 2.1.4
Mockito 2.27.0
Jupiter 5.3.2

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 overloads of `postForEntity` that could take 3 parameters:

- `<T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)`
- `<T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(URI url, Object request, Class<T> responseType)`

In your production code, you are calling the first one.

In your test, you stub the second one instead.
This stems from the fact that in your call:

```
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(response);
```

You provide 3 arguments, and the values provided match types of parameters of the second overload.
Thus the overload with varargs is not even considered.
(any() returns null, which is a good match for both URI and String).

Instead of reflection, I would advise to:

- use constructor injection for sampleVersion
- drop @InjectMocks on the service under test
- instead, construct service under test in a BeforeEach method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this into the answers because the author put the solution into the question. (This is for better visibility.) The author was able to resolve the issue using

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someClass, "field", "value");
```

This can assign the private field a value for testing purposes. The value is not assigned by the `@Value` annotation during the automated test.

For more information on usage: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reflection-test-utils#using-reflectiontestutils-to-set-a-value-of-a-non-public-field